# C# Removing the whole string apart from the end

Tags: c#, string

I want to be able to remove the entire start of a string except for just the end. For example:

```
http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png
```

That is my url/string. I want to remove most of the first bit of the string so it will end up being.

```
a_image.png
```

What is the most reliable and efficient way to do this?

Comment: `stone_icon32.png` isn't a part of your URL.

Comment: What do you men by most of the string? is it the image name you want or the extension?

Comment: Use `LastIndexOf('/')` to get the position of the last '/', then use `Substring` to get the desired part.

Comment: @SamuelSlade Fixed it now.
I want both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string str="http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png";
str=str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Honestly, Mithrandir's answer is the best and most stable

Comment: @OskarKjellin, I think your is better)))

Comment: @mesiesta I think his would be fadter as it is already split into segments

Answer (score 11):

```
Uri myuri = new Uri("http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png
");

String last_part = myuri.Segments[myuri.Segments.Length-1];
```

or

```
String last_part = myuri.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: Hah you beat me to it. Much better than splitting the string. My only two pennies: `myuri.Segments.Last()` would probably be more readable.

Answer (score 9):

[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) will do this for you.

```
Path.GetFileName("http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png");
```

Returns

> a_image.png

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want is to get the final part of your URL (i.e. the value after the last `/` character), then you can use the [`String.LastIndexOf(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) method. So you could do something like the following:

```
string url = @"http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png";

int breakIndex = url.LastIndexOf('/');
string lastFragment = url.Substring(breakIndex + 1);
```

This will give you the result of "a_image.png".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var str = "http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png";
var reqdstr = str.Split('/')[str.Split('/').Count()-1];
```

Comment: I'm not convinced splitting twice and enumerating over an array will be the "efficient way to do this".

Comment: @BuhBUh you don't need to split twice, I'm just lazy that I wrote in single line. You can split once and pass it to a new var to work on it instead..

Answer (score 1):

Simple way (quite unsafe tho):

```
string a = "http://www.website.com/images/a_image.png";
string b = a.Remove(0, a.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the URL string based on forward slash (/) which will return an array containing various components of the URL. Use the last index(array.length -1) which will fetch you the image